# Find unrelated records through a many-many relationship in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord, yii

I have an Orders ActiveRecord with the following relation

```
    /**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tests' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Test', 'orderstests(orders_id, test_id)'),
    );
}
```

a Test ActiveRecord with the following relations

```
    /**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'orders' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Orders', 'orderstests(test_id, orders_id)'),
    );
}
```

and a many-many relational record

```
class OrdersTests extends CActiveRecord
```

I need to get all the tests which are not in a relationship with a particular order, that is a recordset of order_id, test_id doesn't exist for a particular order_id.

I can't seem to find any relations query in Yii for that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [on Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57460-getting-unrelated-records-from-a-many-to-many-relationship/)

```
public static function getTestsNotInOrder($order)
{
    $excludedTestIds = array_keys($order->tests); // This makes use of the index attribute above

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addNotInCondition('id', $excludedTestIds);

    return self::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```